# Beautiful Soup4で動的なクラス名自体を取得するには？

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

BS4初心者、というかWebスクレイピング初心者です。
スクレイピング対象のサイトの作りが表データと表を説明するデータで構成されており、Pandasを使い表データ取得や加工等はできるようになったのですが、表以外のデータの取得も必要となりBeautifulSoup4を併用することで考えています。
取得する必要があるのは動的に変更となるclass名自体になります。
reなどでワイルドカードを利用したclass名指定による値取出しはできるのですが、今回の場合、class名自体を取得したいのです。

サイトの例示は以下のようになります。

```
    <div class="Kategorie science"> ←"Kategorie science"の部分が動的に変る
<h2 class="TitleName">XXXの本</h2>
<span class="TitleDetail Level-1">XXXXXX</span>
<div class="TitleLabels">
    <span class="label Level-1">XXXXXXX</span>
</div>
```

このようなサイトデータから"Kategorie science"（実際には都度動的に変更となります）を取得したいのです。

アドバイスを頂けると幸甚です。

Comment: htmlソースの断片だけ提示されても助言や回答は難しいのでは？ 差し支えなければ実際の対象URLを示すか、全体的な構成は維持して特定/公開されたくない情報だけは何か別の物に置き換える(ただし置き換えた中でも違う物は区別が付くようにする)などして提示した方が良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(回答付いてるけど, 少し異なるような？記述として)

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = '''
...     <div class="Kategorie science"> ←"Kategorie science"の部分が動的に変る
... <h2 class="TitleName">XXXの本</h2>
... <span class="TitleDetail Level-1">XXXXXX</span>
... <div class="TitleLabels">
...     <span class="label Level-1">XXXXXXX</span>
... </div>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

最初に見つかる divの class

```py
>>> soup.div['class']
['Kategorie', 'science']
```

すべての divの class属性を持つもの (から属性のみ表示)

```py
>>> soup('div', class_=lambda v: print(v))
Kategorie
science
Kategorie science
TitleLabels
TitleLabels
[]
```

Comment: oririさん。ありがとうございます。lambdaを利用した方法もあるのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup('''<div class="Kategorie science"> ←"Kategorie science"の部分が動的に変る
... <h2 class="TitleName">XXXの本</h2>
... <span class="TitleDetail Level-1">XXXXXX</span>
... <div class="TitleLabels">
...     <span class="label Level-1">XXXXXXX</span>
... </div>''', 'lxml')

>>> classes = [d['class'] for d in s.findAll('div')]
>>> classes
[['Kategorie', 'science'], ['TitleLabels']]
```

とか

Comment: quickquipさん、ありがとうございます。そういう手がありましたね。beautifulsoupだけでやらなきゃいけないと思い込んでいました。